# What is the error in these mysql query returning no rows when run through mysql_query()?

Tags: mysql, rows

The query is:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   press_release
WHERE
   posted_by != '1' AND
   LOCATE('1',send_id)
ORDER BY
   date_added DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

when i run these query in  `PHP my admin` it will give me 2 rows but i run these query with `MySQL_query()` it will give me zero rows. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if `mysql_error()` returns an error. Instead of using `LOCATE('1',send_id)` have you tried using the following:

```
SELECT * FROM press_release WHERE posted_by != '1' AND send_id = 1 ORDER BY date_added DES C LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is in your query

your Query

```
 SELECT * FROM press_release WHERE posted_by != '1' AND LOCATE('1',send_id) ORDER BY date_added DES C LIMIT 0,10
```

Which should be

```
SELECT * FROM press_release WHERE posted_by <> '1' AND LOCATE('1',send_id) ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Mysql not equal to sign is not != it should be <> and your DESC have an space

Comment: i think `!=` and `<>` are one and the same thing. source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal